# ActiveAdmin skip Authentication for a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Here is my routes:

```
                   admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)                admin/admin_users#index
                                     POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)                admin/admin_users#create
                new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)            admin/admin_users#new
               edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)       admin/admin_users#edit
                    admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)            admin/admin_users#show
```

This line in config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

will  automatically call an authentication method in a before filter of all controller actions to ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
So how can I make an exception so I can go to

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_users/new
```

to create a new admin without logged in?

**Update:**
I added skip_before_action to my controller

```
  ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
      permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number
      controller do
        skip_before_action :authenticate_admin_user!, only: :new
      end
  ...
  end
```

It gives me this error:
`Before process_action callback :authenticate_admin_user! has not been defined`

Comment: Have your tried 'skip_before_action' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the callback responsible for authentication, e.g. authenticate_admin_user.
2. Add skip_before_filter :authenticate_admin_user to controller do block.

   ```
   ActiveAdmin.register User, as: "User" do
    controller do
     skip_before_action :authenticate_admin_user!, only: :new
    end
   end
   ```

Above code will skip the callback for that particular controller.

Comment: Can you explain more where can I find the callback for authentication? I can't find anywhere has the "authenticate_admin_user" except in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`. In the `app/controllers/` there is only a file name application_controller.rb. Sorry, I'm very new to Rails.

Comment: Type filters(:before) and you will see a list of callbacks.
Now find the  callback responsible for authentication.

Comment: What do you mean "type filter(:before)"? I tried everywhere but can't find it. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: add binding.pry in the controller block and then type filter(:before) which will list filters and then find the callback responsible for authentication.

Comment: It gives me the error as I edit in my post "Before process_action callback :authenticate_admin_user! has not been defined"

Comment: this error signifies that the callback does not exist..have you commented out the initializers code for the authentication??

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_active_admin_user
```

works fine by me.

Actually, when listed callback actions, found it in the list.

By investigating in the activeadmin gem basecode, found this:

```
before_action :authenticate_active_admin_user
```

in lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb. That is the before filter added for all controllers.

One can skip an action only if defined (defined does not only mean the actual method is defined, but an action must be defined in the stack with before_action, ie put there by a former before_action).

The line in the ActiveAdmin conf

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

is about the method called but not the name of the action.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you want to skip authentication (AdminUsers I suppose)...

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_admin_user!, only [:new]
```

Answer (score 0):

`authenticate_active_admin_user` gives you access to the active admin authenticate user

```
controller do 
  skip_before_action :authenticate_active_admin_user, only: :new
end
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nsm-activeadmin/0.2.2/ActiveAdmin%2FResourceController%3Aauthenticate_active_admin_user

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb#L38